# Cómo puedo cambiar el estilo de las flechitas (up/down) de un Campo input type=number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, materialize

Explico un poco lo que deseo:estoy usando el framework Materializecss y tengo varios inputs type= number en mi formulario. Lo que deseo es darle un mejor estilo a las flechitas de incremento (up) y decremento(down) que por defecto le aparecen a ese tipo de campos. Se que son flechitas que las coloca el navegador, pero estoy haciendo un proyecto y me piden para el diseño de esos campos que esa area donde estan las flechitas se de color negro y los triangulitos de las flechitas que sean de color blanco.

Comment: Hola N.bravoA, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general, y que leas [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para mejorar tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, sería idea que añadieras el código que lleves (para que podamos verlo), lo que hayas intentado, y los problemas/errores que te estés encontrando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay forma sencilla de modificar directamente los botones del input con css, lo que puedes hacer es agregar dos botones "div" y con un script cambiar el valor del input dependiendo el boton que clikeen

ejemplo:

```js
    jQuery('<div class="quantity-nav"><div class="quantity-button quantity-up">+</div><div class="quantity-button quantity-down">-</div></div>').insertAfter('.quantity input');
    jQuery('.quantity').each(function() {
      var spinner = jQuery(this),
        input = spinner.find('input[type="number"]'),
        btnUp = spinner.find('.quantity-up'),
        btnDown = spinner.find('.quantity-down'),
        min = input.attr('min'),
        max = input.attr('max');

      btnUp.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue >= max) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue + 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
        //SelectorSlide.val(newVal);.    /*aquí pone el selector del slide*/
        spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

      btnDown.click(function() {
        var oldValue = parseFloat(input.val());
        if (oldValue <= min) {
          var newVal = oldValue;
        } else {
          var newVal = oldValue - 1;
        }
        spinner.find("input").val(newVal);
       //SelectorSlide.val(newVal);        /*aquí pone el selector del slide*/
       spinner.find("input").trigger("change");
      });

    });
```

```css
.quantity {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number]
{
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.quantity input {
  width: 45px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.quantity-nav {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 42px;
}

.quantity-button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  line-height: 1.7;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-up {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.quantity-button.quantity-down {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <input type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" value="1">
</div>
```

créditos: https://codepen.io/komarovdesign/pen/PPRbgb

Comment: Respuesta Editada*

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu aporte a la solucion de mi problema. Utilice el codigo y realmente el diseño de las flechitas del input cambio como queria, pero ahora se me presenta otro problema. Yo tengo un slider debajo de ese input, entonces cuando muevo los handles del slider el valor en el input va cambiando, y cuando yo clickeo en las flechitas del input los handles el slider deben moverse, es decir el cambio de valor en el input debe verse reflejado tambien en el slider. Ahora con este diseño nuevo yo le doy a las flechitas del input y el slider no se mueve. Cómo podria hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Código editado* en el js le agregué las líneas para que ponga el selector del slide...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow @N.bravoA , te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, así también te invito a leer [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2924/47499) que yo mismo hice, si tu problema consta de dos rubros diferentes, realiza una pregunta para cada uno por separado.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia alexchvrches, no conozco con exactitud el funcionamiento del sitio. Hare otra pregunta con el segundo problema.

Comment: Ya le  di una posible solución para el segundo "problema" q tiene @N.bravoA

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución que me dio, me ha funcionado muy bien y pude integrar el slider.